# Complete WebBrowser Control On All OSes?

Tags: browser

I want to create a new application (which I will sell) that uses web browser control to automatically post things on the internet etc.

I did some research, and it looks like the primary choice for most people is .NET webbrowser control (via an instance of IE).

I don't want to do this because I want customers that own a Mac and Linux to be able to use my software.

With that said, are there any web browser control classes or toolkits available that can work on all OSes (e.g. something that uses Java?)

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Web browser control is basically the ability for a program to act like a human and open a web browser and go to websites, fill out forms, check email (lol) etc.

Comment: What is a "web browser control?"

Comment: @MattBall: An embedded browser

Comment: https://www.google.com/chrome

Comment: @CodyGray Lol? I've already got chrome thank you, or are you trying to send me a subliminal message?

Comment: You're asking for a browser that runs on all OSes. Chrome is exactly that.

Comment: I see, good point. Is there any way for me to control it? I think chrome extensions may be the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) libraries let you create scripts (with a GUI or one of the supported languages [it has got most of the popular ones like Java, Python etc.]) for browser automation on all popular browsers (including chrome, which works on all OSes like mentioned by other answers).

Answer (score 0):

Firefox, Chrome, Safari. I think virutally everything but IE works on all the OS's. Not suprising really when you think it's made by microsoft.